Implement generic SHA hashing utilizing type-state pattern

This is for no_std environment, with no alloc available.

I am interested in implementing a frontend for generic SHA2 calculation (that is supporting different SHA2 types, as in SHA2_256, SHA2_384 etc), while utilizing types-state pattern. The general structure as I see it should be similar to the following:
const SHA_256_CTX_LEN: usize = 64;
const SHA_256_HASH_LEN: usize = 32;

/* Type-states */
pub struct ShaInit;

pub struct ShaUpdate {
    context: [u8; SHA_256_CTX_LEN],
}

pub struct ShaFinal {
    hash: [u8; SHA_256_HASH_LEN],
}    
///////

impl ShaInit {
    pub fn init() -> ShaUpdate {
        let mut sha_update = ShaUpdate {
            context: [0u8; SHA_256_CTX_LEN],
        };
        /* Call actual update logic on sha_update
        ...
        */
        sha_update
    }
}

impl ShaUpdate {
    pub fn update(&mut self, data: &[u8]) {
        /* Perform update in-place, intermediate state is in self.context
        ...
        */
    }

    pub fn finalize(&mut self, data: &[u8]) -> ShaFinal {
        let mut sha_final = ShaFinal {
            hash: [0u8; SHA_256_HASH_LEN],
        };
        /* Call actual sha function on sha_final
        ...
        */
        sha_final
    }
}

impl ShaFinal {
    pub fn get_hash(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.hash
    }
}

fn main() -> ()
{
    let mut sha = ShaInit::init();
    sha.update(b"Hello");
    sha.update(b", ");
    let sha = sha.finalize(b"World!");
    
    println!("hash: {:?}", sha.get_hash());
}

Link to Playground
That is, each calculation is going through 3 states - uninitialized (ShaInit), initialized (ShaUpdate) and finalized (ShaFinal).
It works fine as long as there is single SHA type to be calculated, but I am interested in having a more generic way to accommodate different SHA types. That is to have something like:
struct ShaType256;
struct ShaType384;
struct ShaType512;

impl ShaType for ShaType256 {}
impl ShaType for ShaType384 {}
impl ShaType for ShaType512 {}

pub struct ShaInit<T: ShaType> {...}
pub struct ShaUpdate<T: ShaType> {...}
pub struct ShaFinal<T: ShaType> {...}

The problem is that the context and the hash length (and perhaps some other state variables) are depending on the specific SHA type and basically ShaUpdate<Sha512> structure is different field-wise from ShaUpdate<Sha256>. The closest thing to what I am looking for that I found is the "const generics" semantics, but that would require passing constants for each varying array, while I'd like these to be "derived" somehow from the single Sha type parameter.
Is there any way to do this or something close enough to it (preferably with stable Rust)?

Aren't you just looking for associated const items on  ShaType⁉

Your ShaType could have associated types for Context and Hash, which could be constrained eg to BorrowMut<[u8]> so that you can obtain a slice with which to work.

@cafce25: you can't use associated const items in const generic expressions such as array lengths though (at least not on stable).

@cafce25 Perhaps. Could you please elaborate? I haven't found how to do it.

@eggyal Ah you're right, that's not available on stable, it would look something like this on nightly.

@cafce25 oh, this is nice. I wonder if it is stabilized any time soon.

@eggyal I guess I am going to follow your suggestion (if I understood you correctly) by having the max length for the arrays and bounding them based on the trait defined constant value.. and wait for generic_const_exprs stabilization

I actually meant something like this.

@eggyal Ah.. I knew there must be some type magic... I need to digest it.

@eggyal Looks like it is the next best thing after the unstable generic_const_exprs and is pretty much exactly what I am looking for. I'd consider it an acceptable answer if it is posted as one.

Another option would be to use typenum and generic-array to get even closer to the unstable approach with const generics, but then you're pretty much just recreating the sha2 crate.
